# After form submit no json_encode of post data

Tags: php, html, json

i am trying to get some output from this code but i didn't get what i won't.

Here Code:

```
  <?php
       if(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send']=="Send"){
        $array = $_POST['message'];
        $var = call_user_func_array("json_encode",$array);
        $var2 = call_user_func_array("json_encode",array(&$array));
        echo "var => ".$var."\n";
        echo "var2 => ".$var2."\n";
    }
    ?>
```

output

```
var => var2 => "array('a'=>1,'b'=>2)"
```

need

```
var => 1 var2 => {"a":1,"b":2}

<div class="container">

      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">Message:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">          
            <textarea class="form-control" required id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter Message">array('a'=>1,'b'=>2)</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Send" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send']=="Send") {
$array = $_POST['message'];
$array = eval($array);
$var = "";
if (is_array($array)) {
    $var = json_encode($array);
}
echo "var => ".$var."\n";       
}
```

Comment: @Gulshan define "not working". What output does this solution give you?

Comment: @ADyson this is output var => var2 => "array('a'=>1,'b'=>2)"

Comment: @Gulshan I doubt it. This example doesn't even include the string `var2 =>`, so there's no way that could be included in the output. Have you actually tried it? A very similar example: `$array = array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
$var = "";
if (is_array($array)) {
    $var = json_encode($array);
}
echo "var => ".$var."\n"; ` produces `var => {"a":1,"b":2}`

Comment: actually i am sending data through post..static its working but when send this data through post its converted in a string.

Comment: @Gulshan i realise that, mine was just a simplified example to demonstrate that what you reported in your earlier comment as being the output of this code was impossible. perhaps you should show us what your POST data looks like?